# Let $a=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[5]{5} \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $a$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ and that $|\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}|\le 30$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I know that if $a$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ then there exists minimal polynomial $f(x)\in Z[x]$ such that $a$ is the root of that polynomial. I am trying to find that polynomial which I know will be of degree $30$ so that $|\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}|\le 30$.

I have looked at other examples on this forum like when $a=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ or $a=\sqrt[3]{2}$ or $a=\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[3]{9}$ and looked at their methods of finding the required polynomial but each method is different and the given $a=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[5]{5}$, it is difficult to find its polynomial using any their methods.

If I try solving it following way $(a-\sqrt{2})^2=(\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[5]{5})^2 \Rightarrow a^2+2-2a\sqrt{2}=\sqrt[3]{9}+\sqrt[5]{25}-2\sqrt[3]{3}\sqrt[5]{5}$ and then go on from there, then I get a messy equation which can't be solved to get a polynomial $f$ in $a$ for which $f(a)=0$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using [polynomial resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) you can eliminate $x,y,z$ between $a=x+y+z$, $x^2=2$, $y^3=3$, $z^5=5$ to obtain a rational polynomial in $a$ of degree $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$. The calculations are routine, but laborious.

Comment: Are you sure you really want this degree-30 polynomial? What are you going to do with it, other than stare at it and admire it? My experience is that doing a computation can be very instructive, but the final result is usually not so.

Comment: The answer to the original question is to prove $a$ is algebraic and to show it thus, we have to show there exists a minimal polynomial by producing it. Is there any other way to show that $a$ is algebraic? If not, then just doing the initial calculations to show the polynomial exists should suffice. The whole polynomial need not be reproduced.

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%2B%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B3%7D%2B%5Csqrt%5B5%5D%7B5%7D) knows the answer. It's not pretty.

Comment: Thanks for the WA link. I guess is there another way to prove that $a$ is algebraic without finding the minimal polynomial? The only definition of algebraic number is to show the polynomial but if it is not pretty, there must be another way to prove it is algebraic.

Answer (score 3):

You can check that the polynomial in $x$

$$\prod_{u, v, w} ( x - u \sqrt{2} - v \sqrt[3]{3} - w \sqrt[5]{5})$$
where $u$ runs trough $\pm 1$, $v$ through cubic roots of $1$, and $w$ through $5$-th roots of $1$, has all coefficients integral . Note that there are $2\cdot 3\cdot 5$ factors in the product. One of the roots of your polynomial is your number $a$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $a \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt[5]{5})$ which is a finite extension of $\mathbb Q$ of degree at most $30$:
$$
[\mathbb Q(u,v,w):\mathbb Q]=[\mathbb Q(u,v,w):\mathbb Q(u,v)][\mathbb Q(u,v):\mathbb Q(u)][\mathbb Q(u):\mathbb Q] \le 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 30
$$
where $u=\sqrt{2}$, $v=\sqrt[3]{3}$, $w=\sqrt[5]{5}$.